# Mysql / PHP add AND if multiple $_POST data is entered

Tags: php, mysql, post, if-statement

i have multiple POST data fields in a form and want to query to mysql database, if just one POST data field is entered every thing is working, but if theres two or more fields i get error because i need to enter AND between my questions.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM  `medlem` WHERE";

if(!empty($_POST[fnamn])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fnamn']);
    $sql .= " `Fornamn` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[enamn])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['enamn']);
    $sql .= " `Efternamn` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[adress])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adress']);
    $sql .= " `adress` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[postnr])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postnr']);
    $sql .= " `postnr` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[stad])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stad']);
    $sql .= " `stad` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[pnr])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pnr']);
    $sql .= " `pnr` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[tfn])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tfn']);
    $sql .= " `tfn` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[mobil])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobil']);
    $sql .= " `mobil` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if(!empty($_POST[epost])){
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['epost']);
    $sql .= " `epost` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
```

If a user have filled two post fields the sql i get "SELECT * FROM  `medlem` WHERE Fornamn`LIKE 'foo' Efternamn` LIKE 'bar', and there is a missing AND between them.
Is there an easy solution to this problem ?

Arash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in cycle

```
$params = array(
    'fnamn' => 'Fornamn',
    'enamn' => 'Efternamn',
    'adress' => 'adress',
    'postnr' => 'postnr',
    'stad' => 'stad',
    'pnr' => 'pnr',
    'tfn' => 'tfn',
    'mobil' => 'mobil',
    'epost' => 'epost'
);
$condition = array();
foreach ($params as $key => $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key]);
        $condition[] = "`{$field}` LIKE '%{$a}%'";
    }
}

$slq = 'select * from `medlem` where '.implode(' and ', $condition);
```

Comment: @ArashShiri, please set same name of post data as column's name

Comment: Also pay attention to the Madara Uchiha's answer. It's important!

Answer (score 2):

### STOP!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

The reason you're seeing this, is because you are building your queries without `OR` or `AND`. (Which are needed to seperate logical statements).

The best solution would be to add all of the query parts into an array, and implode with the a delimiter of `" AND "`.